# php password_hash equivalent in livecode

Tags: livecode

In `php`, we have a `password_hash` function to create a password hash. Do we have an equivalent for this function in livecode?

Password has function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: you can use md5 function too

Comment: @NishantSaini MD5 is a bad (outdated) hash function for passwords. If you can, use PBKDF2 hashes, bcrypt or scrypt. MD5 is too easy to reverse with today's fast computers. See https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm for more info. Sadly, the best hash function LiveCode provides at the moment is SHA-1.

Comment: i know that you can use both md5+hash to make more secure your password  hash('sha256', md5('password'));

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php PHP's `password_hash` function uses **bcrypt** as the underlying algorithm.

I don't think LiveCode has bcrypt support natively, so you may need to install an external into your stack or call out to the command line using the `shell` function to get a decent hash.